# Generic set theoretic intersection of two high codimensional varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-cycles

Let $X$ be a complex projective variety, let $Y$ be a fixed subvariety. Consider all effective irreducible algebraic $r$-cycles where $r$ is fixed and chosen in a way such that $r \ll \text{Codim}_X(Y)$. Intuitively it seems that any such cycle $Z$ if chosen randomly is not going to have any set theoretic intersection with $Y$. Is something like the following statement true?

- Space of irreducible cycles with fixed degree $d$ (you can assume $d$ is also small compared to $\text{Codim}_X(Y)$ if it matters)that do not intersect $Y$, form a dense subset of the Chow variety $C_{r,d}(X)$. (again if matters we can only focus on the cycles that are not completely inside $Y$ i.e. space $C_{r,d}(X)\setminus C_{r,d}(Y)$)

Comment: The Chow variety can easily have components that are single points, for example if there is some kind of rigid curve on X.  A fixed subvariety Y could easily meet such a subvariety.  On the other hand if you have some kind of homogeneous space like a projective space or something, then the group action can be used to prove something like what you want.  One theorem in this direction is Kleiman's Transversality Theorem, which you can find in Hartshorne or Eisenbud and Harris 3264 and all that.